# ESS-View not working

Tags: ess, r

I have just installed ess-view, following the steps outlined in the installation section [here](https://github.com/GioBo/ess-view). Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
x <- sample(1:10, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(2:11, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
hoo <- data.frame(x, y)
```

After running these commands in R, C-x w allows me to choose the dataframe, but then produces the following error:

"R error during background ESS command 'exists(hoo)'
Error: invalid first argument"

Using the `View` function or other means, this dataframe can be displayed without any issues. Any ideas why this might not be working?

Comment: [ess](https://ess.r-project.org/) doesn't this package suffice? Is there a reason, you are using ess-view? The  aforementioned github repo doesn't even seem to have good number of stars

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am new to the ESS package and am exploring the associated functionality. The in-built `View()` command only seems to allow simple navigation, using the cursor or page-up/-down buttons, but does not seem responsive to `M-<`, `M->`, `M-r` or the trackpad, for example. Searching the manual for `View()` also did not yield anything in that respect, but perhaps there is something I have missed? So, `View()` is nice in principle, I am just looking for a bit more navigation functionality when exploring the data.

Answer (score 1):

The code of [`ess-view`](https://github.com/GioBo/ess-view) *smells* ...

Any idea what [`ess-view-data`](https://github.com/ShuguangSun/ess-view-data) does?

---

This works ...

```lisp
(require 'ess-view)

(defun ess-view-boolean-command (s cmd &optional on)
  (ess-boolean-command
   (pcase on
     (`name
      (format "%s(\"%s\")\n" cmd s))
     (_
      (format "%s(%s)\n" cmd s)))))

(defun ess-view-boundp (s)
  (not (not (ess-view-boolean-command s "exists" 'name))))

(defun ess-view-data-type-is (s type)
  (when (ess-view-boolean-command s (format "is.%s" type))
    type))

(defun ess-view-which-type (s types)
  (unless (ess-view-boundp s)
    (error "`%s' is not bound" s))
  (->> types
       (seq-some
        (lambda (it)
          (ess-view-data-type-is s it)))))

(defun ess-view-inspect-df-inner (row-names save)
  "Show a dataframe.
If ROW-NAMES is t, the row names of the dataframe are also exported.
If SAVE is t, it also saves back the result."
  (or (when ess-view--spreadsheet-program
        (setq ess-view-oggetto (ess-read-object-name "name of R object:"))
        (setq ess-view-oggetto (substring-no-properties (car ess-view-oggetto)))
        (or (unless (ess-view-boundp ess-view-oggetto)
              (message "The object does not exists"))
            (pcase (ess-view-which-type ess-view-oggetto '(vector data.frame matrix))
              (`vector
               (ess-view-print-vector ess-view-oggetto))
              (`data.frame
               (ess-view-data-frame-view ess-view-oggetto save row-names t))
              (`matrix
               (ess-view-data-frame-view ess-view-oggetto save nil nil))
              (_
               (message "the object is neither a vector or a data.frame; don't know how to show it...")))))
      (ess-no-program)))

(defun ess-view-create-env ()
  "Create a temporary R environment.
This is done in order not to pollute user's environments with a temporary
copy of the passed object which is used to create the temporary .csv file."
  (interactive)
  (let ((nome-env (ess-view-random-string)))
    ;; it is very unlikely that the user has an environment which
    ;; has the same name of our random generated 20-char string,
    ;; but just to be sure, we run this cycle recursively
    ;; until we find an environment name which does not exist yet
    (if  (and (ess-view-boundp nome-env)
              (ess-view-data-type-is nome-env 'environment))
        (ess-view-create-env))
    nome-env))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, `ess-view-data` I am also looking into. As per my comment to Saravana, I am still exploring the functionality of the different viewing facilities for ESS and just noticed that `ess-view`wasn't working.

Comment: In `ess-view`, the `exists` function, should pass in a `string` and not a `symbol` ... (This is what meant by `Error: invalid first argument"`) Similarly, in the `environment` case, var should be checked if it exists before its value is sought ... That is what my two function does ...